# Month range picker in ngx-Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-bootstrap

I'm using date-range picker of [ngx bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker) and it is working totally fine. But I want to use it for month-range picker.Is there any way I can customise and use it that way?

I've tried passing property like this [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'YYYY-MM' }"  and omitting date from it but while selecting I still need to select date.

```
<input class="form-control" name="dob" placeholder="Date of Birth" type="text"  bsDatepicker [(bsValue)]="bsValue" [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'YYYY-MM' }">
```

Comment: Did you find any solution? Maybe any other component?

Comment: I'm also struggling with this. no solution yet?

Comment: Seeking solution here too.

Answer (score 0):

People who are still struggling with it can set min view mode of datepicker using minMode property

For the month range picker, in this case, minMode is set to 'month'.
Refer to the official docs for working example and explanation.

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#min-mode